# ggplot is plotting wrong data

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I don't know why, but ggplot gets a plot completely wrong (I don't even know what data it is using). I want to plot teslas stock price and the price of the stock tomorrow. Obviously the plot should just be shifted to the left. It works alright with the base plotting in r:

```
plot(df_result$Tesla_Today, type = "l", col = "red")
lines(df_result$Tesla_Tmr, col = "steelblue")
```

[image: How it should look like]

If I now run the plot with ggplot I get the following result:

```
ggplot(df_result, aes(x = Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Tesla_Tmr), color = "steelblue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = Tesla_Today), col = "red")
```

This is wrong, they should at least look the same. What am I missing here?
[image: How it looks like...]

Comment: `plot` is using index (I think this means sequentially reading the data in order), and `ggplot` is using Date as the x axis?

Comment: Yes thank you so much! I just realized that. Its the simple things one doesn't think about...

Answer (score 2):

You should use the gather function to merge the two columns together and use a categorical variable for the color.

```
df_result%>%
   gather(key = 'Day', value = 'Price', c(2,3))%>%
   ggplot() +
   geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Price, color = Day))
```

I am assuming that your Tesla_Today and Tesla_Tmr columns are indexed 2 and 3

Comment: The problem was the index. Nevertheless, thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

plot is using index (I think this means sequentially reading the data in order), and ggplot is using Date as the x axis?
Thanks @ M.Viking